# How common is it to combine aupAsana and vaishvadeva oblations in a single homa sitting?

Tags: practice, vedic-rituals

AupAsana and vaishvadeva are two nitya-karma-s which involve fire oblations according to various gRhyasUtra-s. How common is it for people to do it in a single sitting, without separate pUrvAnga-s  (ie - everything until AjyabhAga in the Apastamba tradition) and uttarAnga-s (ie - everything after prAjApatya and vyAhRti homa in the Apastamba tradition)? What are traditional arguments for and against doing so?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  This is an excellent question, the kind of question we want to encourage more of on this site.  In any case, whether two Homas can be performed in one sitting without separate Purvangas and Uttarangas is the sort of subject that would be discussed in Jaimini's  Mimamsa Sutras, so that would be a fruitful place to look.

Comment: My understanding is that aupAsana is the first karma performed after sandhyAvandana and vaishvadeva is the last  karma performed before antaryAmi-nivedana. In the Sri Vaishnava ahnikas at least, you see the following order of karmas: prAtaH sandhyAvandanam, aupAsanam, agnihotram, AdhAra shaktyAdi tarpaNam, mAdhyAhnikam, bhagavad-ArAdhanam, vaishvadevam, antaryAmi nivedanam. The remains of the bhagavad ArAdhanam are split equally for vaishvadevam and antaryAmi nivedanam. As a result, the scope of doing it in a single sitting doesn't arise since one is to be done at sunrise & the other at noon.

Comment: @hashable - That's fishy. It is clear from the gRhya-sUtra that aupAsana is done after both sandhyA-s; and these sUtra-s are applicable to shrIvaiShNava-s as well.

Answer (score 4):

Talking to practitioners and examining [this](https://archive.org/stream/apastamba_pUrva_prayoga_srImaTham_2012/apastamba_pUrva_prayoga#page/n29/mode/2up) prayoga text, aupaasana and vaishvadeva are usually done with separate pUrvanga-s and uttarAnga-s. It appears that the these are significantly shortened (no idhmAdhAnam, possibly not even AjyabhAga, no jayAdi etc..).

I suppose that the traditional argument in favor of doing so is as follows:

- sviShTakRt oblation is already included in the pradhAna-homa in both cases - so need for detailed uttarAnga is implicitly removed.
- the sUtra only [specifies](https://archive.org/stream/APASTHAMBAGRUHYASUTRAMSUDARSHANAHARADATHA/APASTHAMBA%20GRUHYASUTRAM%20%28SUDARSHANA%2CHARADATHA%29#page/n137/mode/2up) pariShechana before and after for the aupaasana. The same may be assumed of vaishvadeva.